# Flash question on param name

Tags: flash, param

What are the following lines for?

```
<param name="AllowScriptAccess" VALUE="always"/>
<param name="AllowNetworking" VALUE="all"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

`AllowScriptAccess` **controls whether ActionScript in a SWF is permitted to call JavaScript in the HTML page that contains it.**

- `always`: Always permit ActionScript-to-JavaScript calls.
- `sameDomain`: Permit ActionScript-to-JavaScript calls only when the SWF and HTML page come from the same domain.
- `never`: Never permit ActionScript-to-JavaScript calls.

---

`AllowNetworking` **determines whether the SWF can access the network.**

- `all`: All networking APIs are permitted in the SWF.
- `internal`: The SWF file may not call browser navigation or browser interaction APIs, listed below, but it may call any other networking APIs.
- `none`: The SWF file may not call any networking APIs, listed below. Also, it cannot use any SWF-to-SWF communication APIs, also included in the list below.